How will i get the total no of licenses in the Google Cloud through API
I have one requirement that i need to show all the licenses available in Google Cloud platform from ServiceNow via REST API Method.
Is there anyway i can get the total licenses available
I have used the GET https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/reports/v1/usage/dates/{date} method to get Licenses
Thanks in advance
I'm expecting the total no of licenses and total number of licenses assigned

This seems to only be available for Enterprise accounts or a reseller. You can refer to this article: feedbackEnterprise License Manager API
